# Passing ArrayList from activity to BaseAdapter

Tags: android, arraylist

My application crashes after I call the activity ChunkedImageActivity. All I see is a black screen. I have been told that the problem is in the creation of the arraylist.

My arraylist should contain pieces of an ImageView on which is displayed an image from `R.drawable`.
Here are the code of the second `Activity` and of the `BaseAdapter` called by this activity.

Can you tell me if there is a problem in the creation of the arraylist?

**ChunckedImageActivity**

```
 public class ChunkedImageActivity extends Activity {

 public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){

    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.image_grid);

   //Getting the image chunks sent from the previous activity
   ArrayList<Bitmap> imageChunks = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("image 
   chunks");
    //Getting the grid view and setting an adapter to it
    GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, imageChunks));
    grid.setNumColumns((int) Math.sqrt(imageChunks.size()));
   }
}
```

**ImageAdapter**

```
 package com.example.laptop.gridsplitter;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
 import android.widget.ImageView;

 //The adapter class associated with the ChunkedImageActivity class
 public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Bitmap> imageChunks;
private int imageWidth, imageHeight;

 //constructor
  public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Bitmap> images){
   mContext = c;
   imageChunks = images;
   imageWidth = images.get(0).getWidth();
   imageHeight = images.get(0).getHeight();
 }

@Override
 public int getCount() {
return imageChunks.size();
 }

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
return imageChunks.get(position);
 }

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
return position;
}

@Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ImageView image;
if(convertView == null){
    image = new ImageView(mContext);

    /*
     * NOTE: I have set imageWidth - 10 and imageHeight
     * as arguments to LayoutParams class.
     * But you can take anything as per your requirement
     */
 image.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth - 10 , imageHeight));
    image.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
}else{
    image = (ImageView) convertView;
}
image.setImageBitmap(imageChunks.get(position));
return image;
}
}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
<1> main@830025864456, prio=5, in group 'main', status: 'RUNNING'
  at com.example.laptop.gridsplitter.ImageActivity.onClick(ImageActivity.java:68)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4191)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17184)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java:-1)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java:-1)

<11> Binder_3@830036764080, prio=5, in group 'main', status: 'RUNNING'
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(NativeStart.java:-1)

<10> Binder_2@830036679432, prio=5, in group 'main', status: 'RUNNING'
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(NativeStart.java:-1)

<9> Binder_1@830036678520, prio=5, in group 'main', status: 'RUNNING'
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(NativeStart.java:-1)

<8> FinalizerWatchdogDaemon@830036661992 daemon, prio=5, in group 'system', status:    
 'WAIT'
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:214)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

<7> FinalizerDaemon@830036661560 daemon, prio=5, in group 'system', status: 'WAIT'
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:102)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:73)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:169)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

<6> ReferenceQueueDaemon@830036661200 daemon, prio=5, in group 'system', status: 'WAIT'
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
  at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:129)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

<5> Compiler@830036660960 daemon, prio=5, in group 'system', status: 'WAIT'
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(NativeStart.java:-1)

<3> Signal Catcher@830036660480 daemon, prio=5, in group 'system', status: 'WAIT'
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(NativeStart.java:-1)

<2> GC@830036660256 daemon, prio=5, in group 'system', status: 'WAIT'
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(NativeStart.java:-1)
```

Comment: Better to create image Path `ArrayList` and send,instead of sending `Bitmap ArrayList

Comment: is this the LogCat you need?

Comment: I cannot copy the logcat of variables from android studio intellij.

Comment: Thanks M D, i have never tried it, what is the syntax?

Comment: @JuliusBeta  got any solution for this??